# What does Credential-Option of Invoke-WebRequest add to httpRequest?

Tags: powershell, networking, invoke-webrequest

## Question

I think Credential Option would add something to requestHeader, but it looks like nothing was added.
Does Credential Option change other part of httpRequest?

## Environment

windows10 
PowerShell 5.1.17134.765
analyzed request with Fiddler4.

## Execute Command

```
$cred = Get-Credential // input user and password
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://abc.xyz' -Credential $cred
```

## Request Contents(by Fiddler4):

### Raw Headers

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; ja-JP) 
WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17134.765
Host: abc.xyz
```

### Auth

```
No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.
No Authorization Header is present.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it will only supply the credentials to the remote server if the remote server sends an authentication challenge request.

So it won't do anything unless the target web server requests authentication.

You can apparently use it in conjunction with "-Authentication" to force it to try and authenticate with a specific type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6